# How to use PHP functions from external file in HTML image tag?

Tags: php, html

I have an external PHP file that does some image resizing (image.php). I need to call it every time a 'image' tag is used so it can fill in the "src". How would I tell the HTML file to use the external PHP page and how would I make it use it when processing the 'image' "src" tag?

This is what im using to try to display the image.

Do i need to include something in my     'head' section?

thanks for the help!

```
<li><a href= "/intPics//1.jpg"> <img src="<?php loadImage('/intPics//1.jpg', 300,300) ?>"<div>1.jpg</div></a></li>
```

This is the PHP file

```
<?php



   function imageResizer($url, $width, $height) {



                header('Content-type: image/jpeg');



                list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($url);



                $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;



                if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {

                  $width = $height*$ratio_orig;

                } else {

                  $height = $width/$ratio_orig;

                }



                // This resamples the image

                $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);

                imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height,     $width_orig, $height_orig);



                // Output the image

                imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);



        }



        /    /works with both POST and GET

        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];



        if ($method == 'GET') {



                imageResize($_GET['url'], $_GET['w'], $_GET['h']);



         } elseif ($method == 'POST') {



            imageResize($_POST['url'], $_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);

         }



      // makes the process simpler

        function loadImage($url, $width, $height){

         echo 'image.php?url=', urlencode($url) ,

         '&w=',$width,

         '&h=',$height;

        }



?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly but I'll try to answer:

You could call the php script directly from the `src` in your image tag

```
<img src="image.php" />
```

and in your php file you would set the content-type to an image format

```
<?php header('Content-Type:image/jpeg'); ?>
```

This way the php script returns an image. You could even pass paramters, e.g. `image.php?width=200&height=100` to the php script.

Comment: I posted some code, maybe that can help clarify, sorry its hard to understand. I'm not too sure on how to word my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have in your php file, but

```
<?php require_once('path/image.php') ?>
```

should import it, then you just use the functions and fill the src by a php script?

Edit: If you give me further information, p.e. the code, I can help you witz further questions on details.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do...
http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-resize-images-on-server-side/